# Using IIS rewrite rules to rewrite from main website to sub application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

We have an ASP.NET Web API application (.NET 4.*) which is hosted as a website in IIS. The ASP.NET application contains server-side rendered pages, but also a REST API which is available at /api/v1.

A new API is in development, which is using ASP.NET Core (.NET 7) and will be hosted as an IIS application (believe me, we cannot get around that for now) under the main website (which contains the ASP.NET Web API application).

The new API should also be available on /api, but since this is an application under the main website, if we would use /api for the new application, the REST API of the main website would not receive requests anymore. Hosting it under /api/v2 is not possible as IIS applications cannot contain a / in the alias (and we also do not prefer a version in the path anymore).

Instead, we would like to create the application using another name, /foo for example, and use rewrite rules in the web.config to rewrite from the main website to the new application, eg.:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Foo">
          <match url="^api\/((?!v1).*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="foo/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It looks like the request is rewritten, but still handled by the main website, not by the sub application. Is it not possible to rewrite (not redirect!) a request from a website to a sub application within that website? If not, any other suggestions to host both applications on the same starting path (it should remain two separate applications)? At the moment, there is no possibility for a reverse proxy which could solve this issue.

Comment: Then if you even spend a minute finishing the tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module you will see you get things in `match` and `action` in the wrong order. What you wrote is to rewrite from `api/*` to `foo/*` which is just the opposite of what you wanted. To reveal how the rule engine works, enable FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi No that is not the opposite of what I want. I want every request with a path that starts with /api, but not with /api/v1, to be rewritten to /foo, and thus be 'forwarded' to the sub application.

Comment: Please read the tutorial. If you don't know what are the correct "from" and "to" in rewrite rules, then you will never get it right.

Comment: Please try to use FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access requests starting with /api by typing /foo in the browser address bar, you can try the following rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Foo">
          <match url="foo(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```